# C# HttpListenerRequest QueryString UTF-8 decoding issue

Tags: c#, utf-8, query-string, httplistenerrequest

I've written a http service using `HttpListener`.
The service receives GET requests, with a single query string variable `req` that holds all parameters in a json-encoded string, then performs some tasks.

The requests are generated from other servers and query strings are url-encoded using UTF-8.

The problem is that the `Request` object from the `HttpListenerContext` instance is decoding the query string using `Encoding.Default` rather than UTF-8.

For example, if I send this request to the server:

`http://myserver/?req={"name":"Micciché"}`

which is properly encoded to this url before being sent:

`http://myserver/?req=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Miccich%C3%A9%22%7D`

(note that the `é` character correctly becomes `%C3%A9` in UTF-8)

when I receive the request on my server and try to read and parse the `req` variable with this code:

```cs
string jsonreq = context.Request.QueryString["req"] ?? "";

MyRequest reqObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRequest> (jsonString);
```

the wrong encoding is applied and the string `"Micciché"` becomes `"MiccichÃ©"`

I've looked for a way to enforce UTF-8 decoding but so far I've found nothing.
Browsing `HttpListenerRequest` class source code on Microsoft GitHub Reference Source, it seems that the applied encoding is extracted from `Content-Type` request header only if there is a body in the request, which is not my case.

So far the only quick & dirty solution I've found is to manually reparse the raw querystring using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` which comes from the `System.Web` namespace which I'd rather avoid:

```cs
NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.Url.Query, Encoding.UTF8);
string jsonreq = qs["req"] ?? "";

MyRequest reqObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRequest> (jsonString);
```

Furthermore, I would like to avoid also the burden of double parsing of the query string (one internal from HttpListenerRequest and one from my code).

How can I force HttpListenerRequest to always decode query strings using UTF-8?

Comment: I think you will have to use your custom parser method, because http listener request doesn't provide an option to customize this. Good thing though is: it will not parse query string until you access `QueryString` property (it's "lazy" property), so no double parsing.

Comment: Do you have a header in the server specifying UTF-8? When the client connects it will automatically change encoding based on the headers in the server.  The response will come back with UTF-8 in the header.

Comment: Thanks @Evk for pointing out the laziness of `QueryString`, I'll stick to my method then. @jdweng the client is sending everything in utf-8: the problem is that the server is not honoring Content-Type and treating the query string with a different encoding.